# WPF: Canvas Z-Index Bug

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, z-index

So I made my own carousel control in WPF. I have stumbled upon a bug and was wondering if anyone knew how I could fix this like a method call or a series of methods calls or some work-around. Here is a print screen of my carousel:

[Carousel Image http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9599/carousele.jpg](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9599/carousele.jpg)

As you can CLEARLY see with this image, my mouse pointer is OVER the button with 16 written on it. But the button with 18 written on it is the one that is blue as if my mouse were over that button. I also set the tooltip to be bound to the content and the tooltip says my mouse is over the button with 18 one it. This should be the CORRECT behavior as 18 is the buttons z-index value. Thus the button with 18 on it should be ON TOP of the button with 16 on it. However, WPF did not render the canvas in such a fashion and I was wondering how to overcome this. I tried canvas.InvalidateArranage(), canvas.invalidateVisual(), canvas.UpdateLayout() but I had no luck. The left side of the canvas shows what it should look like, but the right side fails to produce the same result even though the z-index values are correct, and even this screenshot proves my point that this is a bug in WPF.

Comment: Can you provide some source code?  It could be a bug in WPF or your code.  Without the code, it's just hearsay.

Comment: I could produce source code for you, but it would be the whole control itself since the z-index stuff isnt all in one location.

Comment: Agreed.  There's not enough here to go on.  Please add some code.

Comment: Can you post just the event handlers relevant to a carousel item control?

Comment: I would presume that the event handler handling the mouseover for 18 would move it to the top of the carousel, however, item 14 is at the top, which makes one wonder if there aren't a few other problems as well. I think that to get a clear answer to this question, you're going to have to post some event handling source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In wpf, technically your mouse IS over 18.  The way the events (may) be triggered is as follows:

I'm over "16", call the mouseover for 16
I'm over "18", call the mouseover for 18

Since 18 was the most recently called, it's selected (again, just my guess).

In the event args for the mousemove event (I assume mousemove), make sure to set e.Handled = true, this way it's only processed once